# turn string into time

Tags: python, datetime, strptime

How would I get this string '201806070908' into a datetime object? Right now this is YYYYMMDDMMSS. I could get rid of Seconds (S) if needed. I was looking at strptime() but I'm not sure this could be used. It is possible to convert this? The time is part of a directory name and I am looking to upload the most recent file back to another machine.

If anyone can assist or point me in the right direction, then that would be great. Thanks

Comment: If you only want the most recent one, you can simply compare the strings

Comment: *"I was looking at strptime() but I'm not sure this could be used."* Did you even try?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strptime` should work:

```
import datetime

s = '201806070908'

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, '%Y%m%d%M%S')

datetime.datetime(2018, 6, 7, 0, 9, 8)
```

You can test that this worked:

```
>>> dt.day
7
>>> dt.month
6
>>> dt.year
2018
>>> dt.minute
9
>>> dt.second
8
```

Comment: ty. I got it to work. I found the documentation a bit poor and there are people talking all around me so a bit hard to concentrate. Can't believe I overlooked this. Thanks

Comment: No problem, glad it helped!

Comment: @UCProgrammer I think `'%Y%m%d%H%M'` would make more sense, YYYYMMDDMMSS doesn't seem a likely format, it probably is YYYYMMDDHHMM

Comment: @mata you are correct. I switched that already. didn't think anyone would notice ha

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime
x = '201806070908'
print datetime.strptime(x, '%Y%d%m%I%M%S')
```

Should work.

Comment: Thanks. Sacul got me the answer but I appreciate the response. first time using datetime so please excuse the noob question

Comment: Any time and its happen to every one.(me too) :P